# Cocoa send background window to front

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

At the bottom of this post I included an example project that has my code in it.  I have a Cocoa Application that uses a main default window, and another window nib I created. When the program starts, I want it to load the window nib and show it in front of the default 'MainMenu' nib window. How can I do this? I've tried the following code, but the window is still displayed behind the default window:

```
InfoWindowController *winInfo = [InfoWindowController new];

[winInfo.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[winInfo.window setOrderedIndex:0];
[winInfo.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[winInfo showWindow:self];
```

This is being called from `AppController`, which is a class I added to the MainMenu nib. InfoWindowController subclasses `NSWindowController`.  I have included an [example project here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7195844/WindowExample.zip).

Comment: So, do I get a prize for stumping everyone?

Answer (score 3):

So, I know i'm reviving an old thread, but I was having a similar issue. Try putting `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` in there.